# How many endings must I see in Deus Ex to earn the "Deus Ex Machina" achievement?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I've seen 2 endings by now and I'm wondering how many is required for the achievement.

Any clues on how to get them would also really be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm... not quite sure how to answer your question. There are 4 different endings in the game, each with its own button. Press the button and you get the ending you choose.

Eliza tells you the ramifications of each ending.

Comment: +1 This, and the easiest way to get them is to save before pressing anything and the reloading for each.

Comment: Yep, saving and reloading then viewing each of the 4 endings worked just fine for me

Comment: There's an auto-save right after the kill, so no need to save manually.

Comment: @Arda but then you have to listen to Eliza again, save after she's waffled on for maximum time savings

Answer (score 4):

There are 12 in fact, depending on your actions, 3 will be available as choices, the 4th one always the same: the destruction of the installation.

Comment: To clarify what Ben means (welcome to the site, btw!), there are 4 endings, each with 3 different voice overs, depending on your actions across the course of the game.

Answer (score 1):

There are four endings in total that you can watch. Make sure that before you go down to Eliza that you have spoken to Taggert, Sarif, and Darrow in order to unlock those specific endings.

Comment: Are they not available if you don't?

Comment: Indeed they are not, but that is only for Sarif and Taggert. You cannot miss talking with Darrow and Eliza as they are part of the story progression.